# View dismiss automatically in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

.sheet() dismiss automatically, just after open and the also pop the view on which its shown. Here is the gif file that is depicting the behaviour. As I open the google PlacePicker on "Ice Bath" View, the View dismiss() in back and move to "Edit Program" View. After that sheet is dismiss automatically.

[image]

Here is code that I am using for presenting the sheet. I have removed all unnecessary code. I knew that swiftUI render view if any @State, @Binding or @Publihsed property change. If this change occur in any view in NavigationStack, SwiftUI removed all top view from the stack. But I have cross verify these is no such relation of variables that may cause such behaviour.

```
struct EditNotesView: View {
    
    
    @State var openGooglePlaces = false
    @StateObject var viewModel: EditNotesVM
    @Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var completion: (NotesData) -> Void
    
    init(viewModel: EditNotesVM = EditNotesVM(), note: NotesData,
         bathType: ShowerPrograms,
         completion: @escaping (NotesData) -> Void) {
        
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
        viewModel.note = note
        viewModel.selectedShower = bathType
        self.completion = completion
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            loadView()
        }
    }
}

extension EditNotesView {
    
    func loadView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            
            navigationBarView(action: {
                self.dismiss()
            }, title: Config.title)
                    
              locationView()

            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.loadProgramData()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openGooglePlaces) {
            PlacePicker(address: $viewModel.address, latitude: $viewModel.latitude, longitude: $viewModel.longitude)
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the console you will see that EditView Disappear first that cause the pickerview dismiss()

[image: PickerView]

Just for the test purpose I have tested my code in simple and it works perfect. Here is the simple example code that I have used

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {

            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink("First Screeen") {
                    GooglePlaceView()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct GooglePlaceView: View {
    
    @State var openGooglePlaces = false
    @State private var address = ""
    @State private var latitude = 0.0
    @State private var longitude = 0.0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button {
                openGooglePlaces.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Opne Google Places")
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openGooglePlaces) {
            PlacePicker(address: $address, latitude: $latitude, longitude: $longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to NavigationView which is deprecated in iOS 16.0. From apple documentation [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) I just add this `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` property wrapper to my navigation view and my issue has been resolve.

```
NavigationView { // This is deprecated.
    /* content */
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have written entire logic in SwiftUI if so check these options if you are using anywhere

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.scrollDisabled(true)
```

if you are not only using swiftUI and using swift check if we are setting these options anywhere

```
UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
```

In case if you are using these, then sheet, fullScreenCover, overlay will dismiss when you touch on their views

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the non standard state object code, it's not designed for legacy view model objects you need to learn SwiftUI paradigms. State is a source of truth, create it in parent view and pass down let for read acesss of binding var for write access. State can be a struct, eg

```
struct EditorConfig {
    var note: Note?
    var selectedShower: Shower?
    ///mutating func logic {}
}
```

```
@State var editorConfig = EditorConfig()
.sheet(item: $editorConfig) {
    EditNotesView(config: $editorConfig)
}
```

Comment: Actually the issue is due to NavigationView. I found the solution from apple documentation [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) and just add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` property wrapper to my NavigationView

Comment: Great but you still need to remove this bug `init(viewModel: EditNotesVM = EditNotesVM()`. StateObject init's autoclosure only works if the object is init on the same line.